# How to fix the accents in xterm top bar?

Tags: xterm, character-encoding

I don't have any problem with accent (I'm French) inside xterm. However, like you can see on this screenshot, the top bar of xterm does have some accents issues:

[image]

However my Debian unstable system is in utf8 (so it should be good):

```
$ locale
LANG=fr_FR.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

How can I fix this little bug with xterm top bar?

Comment: Try using the Debian `uxterm` or `lxterm` wrappers.

Comment: It seems that xterm is setting its title with a UTF-8 string, which your window manager interprets as latin-1 and converts to UTF-8, resulting in `Ãⓒ` for `é`. What window manager or desktop environment are you using? What are its localization settings?

Comment: @Gilles, no, it's xterm converting the string from latin1 to utf-8 resulting in that double-encoding.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`xterm` documentation](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#Title%20Modes):

> The window- and icon-labels can be set or queried using control
>   sequences.  As a VT220-emulator, xterm "should" limit the character
>   encoding for the corresponding strings to ISO-8859-1.  Indeed, it used
>   to be the case (and was documented) that window titles had to be
>   ISO-8859-1.  This is no longer the case.  However, there are many appli-
>   cations which still assume that titles are set using ISO-8859-1.  So
>   that is the default behavior.
>
> If xterm is running with UTF-8 encoding, it is possible to use window-
>   and icon-labels encoded using UTF-8.  That is because the underlying X
>   libraries (and many, but not all) window managers support this feature.
>
> The `utf8Title` X resource setting tells xterm to disable a reconversion
>   of the title string back to ISO-8859-1, allowing the title strings to be
>   interpreted as UTF-8.  The same feature can be enabled using the title
>   mode control sequence described in this summary.
>
> Separate from the ability to set the titles, xterm provides the ability
>   to query the titles, returning them either in ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8.  This
>   choice is available only while xterm is using UTF-8 encoding.
>
> Finally, the characters sent to, or returned by a title control are less
>   constrained than the rest of the control sequences.  To make them more
>   manageable (and constrained), for use in shell scripts, xterm has an
>   optional feature which decodes the string from hexadecimal (for setting
>   titles) or for encoding the title into hexadecimal when querying the
>   value.

So your options are:

1. Send the title as latin1:

   ```
   printf '\e]2;%b\a' 'T\0351l\0351chargement'
   ```
2. Set the `utf8Title` resource to true:

   ```
   xterm*utf8Title: true
   ```

   in your resource file.
3. Use the `\e[>2t` sequence to enable `utf8Title` (and `\e[>2T` to disable):

   ```
   printf '\e[>2t\e]2;%s\a' Téléchargement
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `xterm*locale: true` in your `.Xresources`?

Comment: This is not working.